# PHP: Time validation RegEx?

Tags: php, regex

I am using following regex to validate date in format `dd/mm/yyyy` in php:

```
preg_match("/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})/", $e_startdate, $matches)
```

But what will be the regex to validate time in the format `10:20 PM` or `AM`. I want a regex which will validate following format for me.

```
<number><number><colon><number><number><space><AM or PM>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should validate the format you requested:

```
preg_match("/(\d{2}):(\d{2}) (AM|PM)/", $e_startdate, $matches);
```

Note that this is not necessarily a valid time. You *could* enter stuff like 32:62 AM. You need something like this for time validation:

```
preg_match("/(0?\d|1[0-2]):(0\d|[0-5]\d) (AM|PM)/i", $e_startdate, $matches);
```

Mind to match the whole thing case-insensitive (like i did in the second example). Otherwise lowercase `am`, `pm`, etc. are not going to work.

Comment: I want to accept time in 12 hours format only, so your regex `/(0?\d|11|12):(0\d|[0-5]\d) (AM|PM)/i` this will only accept 12 hours format right?

Comment: @elusive: after matching it with preg_match what I'll get in `$matches` variable? I need HH MM and AM|PM as separate array element in `$matches` variable?

Comment: @Prashant: You will get something like this: `11:51 AM` results in `array(0 => '11', 1 => '51', 2 => 'AM')`.

Comment: @Prashant: You're welcome! I just corrected a small error (`10` was missing for the hours part). Be sure to use the latest version!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the regex:

```
(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] [AP]M
```

Comment: The preceding 0 should be optional to accept times in format `1:23 AM' and this would accept '00:00 AM' or '00:49 PM' which are illegal. `(0[1-9]|[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] [AP]M` should work for those.

Comment: I am not getting this part `(0[0-9]|1[0-2])` what it means, if you can explain. Thanks!

Comment: @Prashant: It means `0[0-9]` or `1[0-2]`. `0[0-9]` means `0` followed by any digit. and `1[0-2]` means `1` followed by `0 or 1 or 2`.

Comment: As far as i see, this does not match something like `11:42 AM`, since `1` is not allowed as the first digit.

Comment: But times can also be as 03:35 PM ? then I think second condition of `1[0-2]` will fail?

Answer (score 3):

Regular Expression:

```
(([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])
```

Validates time in MySQL time format. 24 hour time colon separated hours:minutes:seconds hh:mm:ss

Matches: 09:30:00 | 17:45:20 | 23:59:59

Non-Matches: 24:00:00

Comment: /([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/ slight simplification

Answer (score 1):

/\d{2}:\d{2} (AM|PM)/

Answer (score 0):

I started with elusive's answer, but needed a bit more flexibility. This one makes the minutes optional, as well as the space before AM/PM

```
/(0?\d|1[0-2])(:(0\d|[0-5]\d))?[ ]?(A|P)M/i
```